Is it possible to configure different legend keys when multiple legends are drawn for geom_line?
I need to plot the same variables from a number of different datasets. I want to use colour to represent the dataset, and linetype to differentiate between the variables, like in the first plot below.
This is fine, but the default legend key for geom_line isn't the best for discerning colour (something with a fill would be better). I know I can overwrite the legend key to something more appropriate using key_glyph, but this overwrites the linetype legend keys too, like in the second plot.
library(tidyverse)

data_1 <-
  tibble(
    dataset = "Dataset 1",
    x = seq(0, 10),
    y1 = 2 * x,
    y2 = 3 * x
  )

data_2 <-
  tibble(
    dataset = "Dataset 2",
    x = seq(0, 10),
    y1 = 2.2 * x,
    y2 = 3.3 * x
  )

data <- bind_rows(data_1, data_2) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(y1, y2), names_to = "variable")

ggplot(
  data = data,
  mapping = aes(x = x, y = value, colour = dataset, linetype = variable)
) +
  geom_line() +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme_bw()

https://i.imgur.com/xXk8o2S.png

ggplot(
  data = data,
  mapping = aes(x = x, y = value, colour = dataset, linetype = variable)
) +
  geom_line(key_glyph = "rect") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme_bw()

https://i.imgur.com/7trbvyp.png
Created on 2024-08-27 with reprex v2.1.1
It feels like I should be able to set key_glyph inside override.aes and only affect the colour legend, but this doesn't work.
guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1, override.aes = list(key_glyph = "rect")))

The best I've managed is to increase the linewidth of the colour legend key to approximate a square, but this doesn't feel like a very robust solution.

One option would be to use two geom_line but draw only one of the legends for each, i.e. for the first geom_line I set key_glyph="rect" and use show.legend to draw only a color legend, whereas for the second geom_line I stick with the default "path" key glyph and use show.legend to draw only a linetype legend. Additionally I filtered the data by variable to avoid duplicating each line.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  data,
  mapping = aes(x = x, y = value, colour = dataset, linetype = variable)
) +
  geom_line(
    data = ~subset(., variable == "y1"),
    key_glyph = "rect",
    show.legend = c(color = TRUE, linetype = FALSE)
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = ~subset(., variable == "y2"),
    show.legend = c(color = FALSE, linetype = TRUE)
  ) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme_bw()


